# Does $|f(x)| \leq | g(x) |$ imply $\left|\int f(x)\,dx\,\right| \leq |\int g(x) \,dx|$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Does the following hold :

$|f(x)| \leq | g(x) |\implies \left|\int f(x)\,dx\,\right| \leq |\int g(x)  \,dx|$

Is there an example or counterexample of this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another counterexmple: $g(x) = sin(x)$, $f(x) = |sin(x)|$, integrate over more than half a period, for example $[0, \pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $ |1| \leq |1|, |1| \leq |-2|$ but $|1 + 1 | > | 1 - 2 |$.